# REST search for category with custom attribute?

Tags: magento2, category, api, search, rest-api

Is it possible to search for a category by a custom attribute?

I have added a custom attribute "category_code" that i would like to do a rest search on.

Is there a way to do this througt the V1/search interface?

/Thomas

Comment: There does not seem to be a way to achieve this for now, it is impossible for core attributes either.

Comment: Thank Alex, now i know.

Comment: Problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

I did a cut'n'paste of the getList from the ProductRepository. Removed all unnecessary code and changed the constructor.

https://github.com/netrixab/magento2-search-category

Comment: ur module wont compile - can u plz review it?

Comment: Hi @SinaMiandashti I didn't intend to maintain this module. But i included this code in another module and it works fine on Magento 2.1.3 in default mode on php 7.0.14.

Comment: try it ... it says missing interface class while compiling ... can u plz at least maintain it ?

Comment: I've got a similar module here which I'm actively using so it should keep working https://github.com/lingwooc/flatCategory-magento2 Currently working in CE 2.1.7. I've not credited @TNordkvist as I wrote it before I found this.