# Search in specific category rest API

Tags: magento2

I am using this API to search a word apple in all website

```
https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=apple
```

Is there is a parameter can be added to search in a specific category?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107351/rest-search-for-category-with-custom-attribute

Comment: I saw the answer before, but I must integrate the code in github to my code and i don't want that. I need to use the parameter directly like other parameters.